# Verilog code testbench error: port is not a port of dut

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, testbench

```
module test1(input logic A,B,C,D);
 output reg Y; 
 always@(A,B,C,D) begin
  case({A,B,C,D})
    4'b0011: Y<=1;
    4'b0111: Y<=1;
    4'b1100: Y<=1;
    4'b1101: Y<=1;
    4'b1111: Y<=1;
    4'b1110: Y<=1;
    4'b1010: Y<=1;
    default: Y<=0;
  endcase
 end
endmodule
```

The above Verilog code is showing the following error:

```
------- Error Output --------------
test_bench.v:12: error: port ``y'' is not a port of dut.
1 error(s) during elaboration.
```

What is the issue?

Comment: well, `y` is not a port of dut tells you what's wrong. Your problem is in test_bench.v in line 12. We don't know your line numbering, so you're the one who needs to help yourself.

Answer (score 5):

According to the section "12.3.1 Port definition" in [one of the revisions of the Verilog standard](https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/SYNTHBD/12388/1/Verilog%20-%20LRM.pdf), a module includes `[ list_of_port_declarations ] ;` with the following syntax:

```
list_of_port_declarations ::=
      ( port_declaration { , port_declaration } )
     | ( )
port_declaration ::=
      {attribute_instance} inout_declaration
     | {attribute_instance} input_declaration
     | {attribute_instance} output_declaration
```

That means that for your design the ports declaration should be the following:

```
module test1
(
    input logic A,B,C,D, 
    output reg Y 
);
```